# Which are the temperature limits that models as spc or spc/e describe better water in Molecular Dynamics Simulations?

Tags: water, molecules, molecular-dynamics

I would like to simulate an organic molecule in water using spc or spc / e models and carry out an annealing. I think that a good parameter to define the temperature limits is to take into account how these models reproduce the behaviors of the water more appropriately. For example, what happens if I bring my system to 410 K, in this case, water is a gas, but do these models accurately describe their interactions? Or what happens if I bring the system to temperatures of absolute zero or 278 K?

I know that there are works on these topics, but I would like to start my simulations taking into account the real time they are going to take, since they are mainly explorative, for this reason I thought to ask here.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: You are right, I'm going to considerate it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SPC family models for water work decently from the qualitative point of view, but they fail (often quite miserably) at reproducing the real phase diagram of water.
Here is a comparison between a somewhat good model for water (TIP4P, left), the experimental phase diagram (middle) and the phase diagram of the SPC/E model (taken from [Sanz et al, Phys. Rev. Lett. 2004](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.255701)):

[image: Comparison between TIP4P, experimental and SPC/E water phase diagrams]

Things get a bit better if you are only interested in vapour-liquid equilibrium, although the liquid branch is well-reproduced only close to room temperature, as you can see here (taken from [Vinš et al, EPJ Web of Conferences (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1051/epjconf/201611402136)

[image: Vapor-liquid equilibrium for SPC/E water]

I never worked with SPC/E water myself, but if I were forced to use it I'd choose a liquid state at $\approx$ ambient temperature

Comment: Wow! I'm very glad for your answers, this let me understand the limitations of this models. Thank you.